# Searching on UITableView Using UISearchBar Swift 5

Tags: swift, search, tableview

** Note: Two Different arrays TopicTitle and TopicDesc**

> I want to filter data by TopicTitle and it is working fine

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredTitleArray = searchText.isEmpty ? titleArray : titleArray.filter { title -> Bool in
        return title.contains(searchText)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

> Problem is, i am getting TopicTitle filtered but the TopicDescription is not showing according to filtered Cell
>   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use multiple arrays, use a struct

```
struct Topic {
    let title, desc : String
}
```

and declare the (data source) arrays

```
var topicArray = [Topic]()
var filteredArray = [Topic]()
```

Then filter

```
filteredArray = searchText.isEmpty ? topicArray : topicArray.filter { topic -> Bool in
    return topic.title.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
```

The benefit of the `range(of` syntax is the ability to search case insensitive.

Comment: I have my own custom JSON data file. and decode to structs using Codable, How i can append data into this type of array var topicArray = [Topic](), can i do this like var topicArray = [topicCodableStruct]

Comment: I have solved my problem by making my codable struct type array... i learned new thing from you